# Server 2008 DNS forwarders

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I am trying to add a static DNS forward under DNS in Windows Server 2008 R2 however I can't figure it out.

Under Server 2003 you simply add an DNS domain name with it's forwarder IP list.

However under Server 2008 you only seem to be able to add IP addresses. The IP's I enter will not resolve/validate, plus it doesn't appear to allow you to enter a matching DNS domain name.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set up a "conditional forwarder" - a feature which has been moved to a [different place in the MMC snapin GUI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794735%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). It has an own node within the DNS server tree at the same level as the forward and reverse lookup zones now:

[image: dnsmgmt.msc]

(Screenshot from http://alicain.blogspot.de/2008/09/windows-2008-conditional-forwarding.html)